# Merge two sorted arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> I know that similar questions have been asked and I have researched
>   many websites. I have tried to use some of the answers but my code is
>   still not working.
>
> I am going through a previous assignments to help build my knowledge
>   of Java. Please forgive any errors in my code, I am still learning
>   Java.
>
> Here is my question:

Implement a method merge that, given two arrays of sorted integer elements, returns a new sorted array with all the elements of the two input arrays.

Assume that the elements in both input arrays are sorted in non-decreasing order (e.g. [0, 1, 2, 2] and [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]). The returned “merged” array must keep this property (e.g. [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]).

Duplicates are allowed in both the input and the output.

If either one of the arrays are null, return the non-null array as a copy, if both arrays are null, the result should be null as well.

Efficiency requirement: the arrays should be merged in a single pass over the arrays.

> Here is what I've done so far, it doesn't meet the requirements so I need help in order to find the right solution:

```
public class MergeArray {
    public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        if (arr1 == null && arr2 == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (arr1 != null & arr2 == null) {
            return arr1;
        }
        if (arr2 != null & arr1 == null) {
            return arr2;
        }
        int[] merged = new int [arr1.length+arr2.length];

        if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {

                if (arr1[i] <= arr2[i]) {
                    merged[i] = arr1[i];
                    merged[i + 1] = arr2[i];
                }
                if (arr2[i] < arr1[i]) {
                    merged[i] = arr2[i];
                    merged[i + 1] = arr1[i];
                }
            }
            if (arr1.length < arr2.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {

                    if (arr1[i] <= arr2[i]) {
                        merged[i] = arr1[i];
                        merged[i + 1] = arr2[i];
                    }
                    if (arr2[i] < arr1[i]) {
                        merged[i] = arr2[i];
                        merged[i + 1] = arr1[i];
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return merged;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is well explained in multiple places on the Internet. Take a look at [Java program to merge two sorted arrays](http://www.javatechblog.com/java/write-a-java-program-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays/) which showes a graphical explanation of the algorithm. You can change your method to use a single `while` loop as:

```
public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
  if (arr1 == null && arr2 == null) return null;
  if (arr1 == null) return arr2.clone();
  if (arr2 == null) return arr1.clone();       

  int[] result = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
  int i = 0, j = 0, r = 0;
  while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
      result[r] = arr1[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      result[r] = arr2[j];
      j++;
    }
    r++;
  }
  // Copy the remaining elements in array 1 to result
  if (i < arr1.length) {
    System.arraycopy(arr1, i, result, r, (arr1.length - i));
  }
  // Copy the remaining elements in array 2 to result
  if (j < arr2.length) {
    System.arraycopy(arr2, j, result, r, (arr2.length - j));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the null checks with the copy of the not-null array

Comment: Why in the initial check for null array you returning the other array.clone() but not the array itself?

Comment: @Eliyahu defensive copy to ensure that caller won't confuse the arrays, it's not a strict requirement but returning input array is not obvious from the perspective of someone who uses the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different indices for each list.  Don’t use `i` for both lists.

Conceptually you’ll be pulling an item off of one list (and incrementing the index for just that list).

Answer (score 0):

```
Basically merge two unsorted and sorted array both its works:

private static void mergeSorted(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int len = arr1.length + arr2.length;
        int[] arr3 = new int[len];
        int count = 0;
        int arrcount = 0;
        while (arrcount < arr3.length) {
            if (count < arr1.length && count < arr2.length) {
                if (arr1[count] < arr2[count]) {
                    arr3 = arrcount > 1 ? sortArray(arr3, arr1[count],arrcount++) : mapArray(arr3, arrcount++, arr1[count]);
                    arr3 = arrcount > 1 ? sortArray(arr3, arr2[count],arrcount++) : mapArray(arr3, arrcount++, arr2[count]);

                } else {
                    arr3 = arrcount > 1 ? sortArray(arr3, arr2[count],arrcount++) : mapArray(arr3, arrcount++, arr2[count]);
                    arr3 = arrcount > 1 ? sortArray(arr3, arr1[count],arrcount++) : mapArray(arr3, arrcount++, arr1[count]);

                }
            } else if (count < arr1.length) {
                arr3 = arrcount > 1 ? sortArray(arr3, arr1[count],arrcount++) : mapArray(arr3, arrcount++, arr1[count]);
            } else if (count < arr2.length) {
                arr3 = arrcount > 1 ? sortArray(arr3, arr2[count],arrcount++) : mapArray(arr3, arrcount++, arr2[count]);
            }
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
    }


private static int[] sortArray(int[] arr, int val,int count) {
        boolean putVal = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
            if (val < arr[i]) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                int index = i+1;
                arr[i] = val;
                if(arr[index] >0) {
                    val = temp;
                }else {
                    i =index;
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
                putVal=true;
            }
        }
        if(!putVal)
            arr[count]=val;
        return arr;
    }

    private static int[] mapArray(int[] arr, int count, int val) {
        arr[count] = val;
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: its work for two different length array and also unsorted or sorted