# Merge two arrays in java without using extra space

Tags: java, arrays, set, hashset

I have used Set to merge the array as it doesn't contain the duplicate value. I have tried it but after printing the hash set it must be in increasing order but it's not. please help me out

```java
public void merge(int arr1[], int arr2[], int n, int m) {
    // code here
    int i, j;
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);
    Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        hs.add(arr1[i]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        hs.add(arr2[j]);
    }
    Set<Integer> h = new TreeSet<Integer>(hs);
    /* List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(hs);
    Collections.sort(list);
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    */ //System.out.println(list);
}
```

please tell me how to correct this code and get the correct output
the output i'm getting is not in increasing order

Comment: Hint: if you are supposed to merge the arrays without using extra space, then you cannot use a `HashSet` or a `TreeSet`.  Or *any other data structures* other than the input arrays and the output array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two sorted arrays in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365303/merge-two-sorted-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Just use `TreeSet` in place of`HashSet`.  Iterating over the `TreeSet` will return the data in ascending sorted order.

Comment: I have tried using the TreeSet too but the output is same..Is there any chance that due to compiler it's not showing correct output.

Answer (score 0):

A much faster, and shorter approach is by using a Heap.
Check this out:

```
public static void merge(long arr1[], long arr2[], int n, int m) 
    {
        PriorityQueue<Long> pq=new PriorityQueue<>();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            pq.add(arr1[i]);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            pq.add(arr2[j]);
        }
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
            arr1[k]=pq.poll();
        }
        for(int l=0; l<m; l++){
            arr2[l]=pq.poll();
        }
    }
```