# Two arrays. create 3rd array by combining first element of first array with first element of second array and so on

Tags: java, arrays, append

I have two arrays in Java.

```
int[] arr1= {3,13,5}
int[] arr2={4,7,9}
```

I want to create a third array arr3 such that first element in arr1 becomes first element in arr3, first element in arr2 becomes second element in arr3, second in arr1 should become third in arr3 and so on like below

```
arr3={3,4,13,7,5,9}
```

Can someone help with this

Comment: What have you tried so far, and which part did you get stuck on? The official java tutorial is a great place to start in understanding how to interact with an array: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html Hint, a loop that goes through both arrays at the same time and adds an element from each array to a new long array would work nicely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two sorted arrays in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365303/merge-two-sorted-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to merge your arrays. If one array has extra elements, then these elements are appended at the end of the combined array.

```
/**
 * Function to merge two arrays alternatively
 * @param arr1: First array
 * @param arr2: Second array
 * @param array1Length: size of array 1
 * @param array2Length: size of array 2
 * @param arr3: Result array
 */
public static void alternateMerge(int arr1[], int arr2[],
                           int array1Length, int array2Length, int arr3[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    // Traverse both arrays
    while (i < array1Length && j < array2Length)
    {
        arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];
        arr3[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }

    // Store remaining elements of first array
    while (i < array1Length)
        arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];

    // Store remaining elements of second array
    while (j < array2Length)
        arr3[k++] = arr2[j++];
}
```

Above function can be called from main() as below -

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        int arr1[] = {3, 13, 5};
        int array1Length = arr1.length;

        int arr2[] = {4, 7, 9};
        int array2Length = arr2.length;

        int arr3[] = new int[array1Length + array2Length];
        alternateMerge(arr1, arr2, array1Length, array2Length, arr3);

        System.out.println("Alternate Merged Array: ");
        for(int i : arr3)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(i = 0; i < array0.length; i++)
    {
        array2[i] = array0[i];          // populating array2[0 - 3]
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++, i++)
    {
        array2[i] = array1[j];          // populating array2[4 - 7]
    }

    for(i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%2d ", array2[i]);
    }

    System.out.printf("\n");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).